# month with leading 0 getting wrong result from createfromformat

Tags: php

I want to convert this date `2021-02` into `02-2021`, so I did:

```
echo DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m', '2021-02')->format('m/Y');
```

but this return `03/2021`

and the correct result is `02/2021`

Comment: When you don't specify the day, it will use the current one. Feb 29th doesn't exist in 2021, so it moves one day forward.

Comment: `echo DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2021-02-01')->format('m/Y');`

Comment: Although the duplicate title is slightly out, the reason is still the same (relating to February dates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to specify the day:

```
echo DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2021-02-someday')->format('m/Y');
```

for example:

```
echo DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2021-02-01')->format('m/Y');
```